# Rails, Paperclip, S3 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Having strange problem and can not understand what is wrong. All production submitted to heroku. I'm trying to store paperclip attachments on s3 server. But can not make it work on a production and development.

**game.rb**:

```
has_attached_file :image,
                :styles => { :big => "500x500",
                             :tiny => "25x25" },
                :default_url => "/images/game/:style/missing.png",
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS,
                :path => "games/:id/:style.:extension",
                :bucket => 'my-assets'

validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
validates_attachment_file_name :image, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
```

**config/initializers/s3.rb file:**

```
if Rails.env == "production"
  # set credentials from ENV hash
  S3_CREDENTIALS = { :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                     :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
                     :bucket => "my-assets" }
else
  # get credentials from YML file
  S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
end
```

**config/s3.yml**

```
development:
  access_key_id: XXX
  secret_access_key: YYY
  bucket: my-assets

production:
  access_key_id: XXX
  secret_access_key: YYY
  bucket: my-assets
```

After trying to submit I got empty page and server logs tells me this:

```
2014-04-22T17:03:05.984867+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/0241bb4e859805f30efd33cf186468f120140422-2-1093xv6[0]'
2014-04-22T17:03:05.985022+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/0241bb4e859805f30efd33cf186468f120140422-2-1093xv6[0]'
2014-04-22T17:03:06.087486+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: convert '/tmp/0241bb4e859805f30efd33cf186468f120140422-2-1093xv6[0]' -auto-orient -resize "25x25" '/tmp/0241bb4e859805f30efd33cf186468f120140422-2-1093xv620140422-2-dyoalj'
2014-04-22T17:03:06.087486+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: convert '/tmp/0241bb4e859805f30efd33cf186468f120140422-2-1093xv6[0]' -auto-orient -resize "25x25" '/tmp/0241bb4e859805f30efd33cf186468f120140422-2-1093xv620140422-2-dyoalj'
2014-04-22T17:03:06.337480+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/0241bb4e859805f30efd33cf186468f120140422-2-1093xv620140422-2-dyoalj'
2014-04-22T17:03:06.340733+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/0241bb4e859805f30efd33cf186468f120140422-2-1093xv620140422-2-dyoalj'
2014-04-22T17:03:06.549137+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime-type '/tmp/93d8a7cd8991a044877ff351da55677e20140422-2-15pyo7z'
2014-04-22T17:03:06.549137+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime-type '/tmp/93d8a7cd8991a044877ff351da55677e20140422-2-15pyo7z'
2014-04-22T17:03:06.694015+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving games/1/original.png
2014-04-22T17:03:06.694015+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving games/1/original.png
2014-04-22T17:03:07.648471+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7103ms
2014-04-22T17:03:07.648471+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7103ms
2014-04-22T17:03:07.663040+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-22T17:03:07.663040+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
2014-04-22T17:03:07.663040+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/games_controller.rb:50:in `block in update'
2014-04-22T17:03:07.663040+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/games_controller.rb:49:in `update'
2014-04-22T17:03:07.663040+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-22T17:03:07.663040+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-22T17:03:07.663040+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-22T17:03:07.663040+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
2014-04-22T17:03:07.663040+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/games_controller.rb:50:in `block in update'
2014-04-22T17:03:07.663040+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/games_controller.rb:49:in `update'
```

When trying to test on development (local) server error is a bit different:

```
[paperclip] saving /games/images/000/000/001/original/game.png
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1210ms

    Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "my-assets.my-assets.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" port 443):
      app/controllers/games_controller.rb:50:in `block in update'
      app/controllers/games_controller.rb:49:in `update'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your S3 console and make sure the bucket is set to "Do not enable website hosting" in "Static Website Hosting".

I'd recommend you to store your s3 credentials only in ENV variables and dump the s3.yml file. It's more secure.

You could setup your paperclip defaults in the environment files (production.rb, development.rb, test.rb, etc.) like this:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['AWSBucketName'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

you won't need to repeat those in your model (game.rb)